# how to use spacer inside a column that is wrapped with singlechildscrollview?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use spacer inside a column that is wrapped with singlechildscrollview and it gives me an error.

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
```

here is my widget

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(),
          TextFormField(),
          //Spacer()
          Divider(),
          Icon(Icons.block)
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

what should i use? your help is appreciated

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try this out, I added an example using your code, it works:

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        return Form(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(),
                    TextFormField(),
                    Spacer(),
                    Divider(),
                    Icon(Icons.block)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Check this Github issue for much details on the solution above: [Wrapping a Column with an expanded in a SingleChildScrollView throws an exception](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18711#issuecomment-505791677)

Comment: Note that `IntrinsicHeight` is expensive and should be avoided when possible.
from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html:
This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

We can add Spacer in SingleChildScrollview by assigning height to its Child widget and if we want **Scrollable** effect in Smaller device and **Unscrollable** effect on bigger device. we can check device is small or big base on this we assign physics property . As you can see below.

[image]

Function to check device is small or big.

```
          isSmallDevice(Size size)
            {
              return size.height < 675;
            }
```

**Youtube** Demo link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zHMuv6_oPk

**Github Repo link**: https://github.com/paras-28/Using-spacer-inside-Scrollview